# Caching img src that causes redirect

Tags: http, browser-cache, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302, http-caching

I would like to have the browser cache the response from a redirect.

I am setting the `src` attribute on an `img` tag to a url that is a redirect to the final resource. The redirect is only good for a short period of time (e.g. 15 min) but the actual content downloaded is long lived (ie can safely be stored for a year). I am setting `Cache-Control: max-age: <1 year>` on the image response however since the redirect can only be used for 15 minutes, I set `Cache-Control: max-age: <15 minutes>`. How can I tell the browser to use the final response's cache settings and not even bother following the redirect on subsequent page views?

Does it matter what type of redirect (`3XX`) that I use?

This is related to: [Chrome and Safari caching 302 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495231/chrome-and-safari-caching-302-redirect) however i actually *want* the behavior they see as a bug.